# How can I take the closest resources to specific stations from ResourcePool?

Tags: anylogic

I'm simulating a manufacturing process. The stations need a variable number of `ResourcePool` "workers". Let's say there are 5 workers for 4 stations, and I want to simulate that those workers can work indifferently in any of the stations.

The problem is that they are not working in the closest station. Oppositely, even when a worker is next to the station, maybe the furthest worker goes until this station which needs the resource, and then the process starts. Obviously, this is inefficient and doesn't represent the reality.

I already have the workers defined, their shifts, their timetables, etc. I have tried to use the function getNeartestAgent() in 'Customize request choice', but it doesn't work. I also tried to calculate the distance of each agent with getDistance(), but I don't know how to manage it and I'm sure it must be a simpler solution even when I'm not working on GIS.

[31/08/22]
Recently I tried to develop a similar model, and I still have the same problem. The model consists of 3 stations which need 1 unit of ResourcePool. In this pool, there are 2 units. This units are agent type Operario. So, I need to choose the closest unit to the station. I tried several things, the following are just some...:

Service blocks -> Resource selection -> "Nearest to the agent". The agent is the material item, so the unit should go to the closest agent being treated in the station. However, it didn't work (units where to any station indeferently).

Service blocks -> Resource selection -> "Unit with top rating". The Unit rating field was 1/distanceTo(node1.getXYZ()). It didn't work either.

Stations (instead of Service blocks) -> Customize resource choice -> Resource choice condition. I can't stablish a boolean variable related to the unit position, as I can't compare among them.

Function. I can't compare units from ResourcePool, as they are detected as Agent and not as Operario.

ResourcePool. I tried to stablish the priority based on the distance to a certain node. But then I can't call these agents (Operario) from the station. It seems here I can only refer to material items, eventhough I write "unit.(...)".

Does anyone know how can I choose the closest resource to the station in which the task is performed? Should be through Customize resource choice -> Resource choice condition, but I don't know how!

Answer (score 0):

when you use a service or seize block, in the advanced properties, there's an option called "Resource Selection"
You have to choose "Nearest to the agent"

If this doesn't work, it might mean that a resource that is close by and not selected, might be actually busy with something else... you have debug your model in order to be sure that it is not the case.

Comment: Thank you Felipe. The problem is that in my model I have used conveys, conveyors and the ResourcePool (among other things, of course). I mean, in the blocks diagram I didn't need the seize and release blocks for Workers, they do it according to what happens in the stations and the orders given by ResourcePool. Any idea of how to manage it from these blocks? Thank you!